# Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04 on external hard drive

Tags: boot, disk, drive

I insalled Ubunutu on external hard drive and I want to ask you, if my Windows 8 disk will stay untouched after using Ubunutu? Will it run well? Also I tried Live USB and it worked really fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will. You will still be able to boot from your windows hard drive after you unplug your external hard drive. You will also be able to access your windows hard drive for any files that are in there if you want.

The run speeds of your Ubuntu will rely on your read and write speeds of the external hard drive. It is highly recommended that it is running off a USB 3.0 port else the speed limits of a USB 2.0 port will make things a little hard to use when you are running many things (like chrome)

Comment: Also, if you intend to mount and use your Windows 8.x partitions while running Ubuntu then disable fast startup or you could get corruption of the hard disk on the Windows side: http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html